# Wordpress - Use new URL, keep site files at old URL

Tags: wordpress

I built a wordpress website for my client at firsturl.com. They own another URL at secondurl.com, and have decided that they would like their website at secondurl.com instead.

They don't actually have hosting with secondurl.com, they just own the URL, but both URLs are owned through the same hosting company.

Is it possible to keep my site at firsturl.com, but make it look like it is at secondurl.com? More than just redirecting, I need the secondurl.com to always be the main URL.

Comment: Just update your site URL in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend try with domain masking. Here is the reference https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking

Thanks.
Regards,
Ed.